# How can we know if we have received any subscription request in openfire xmpp smack library

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am beginner in xmpp openfire.I am creating an android chat application.

I know how we can send and accept subscription request in openfire.**But how can we know if user has received any subscription request from other user in android?**

I have searched around the internet for this but didn't find any satisfactory answer.

Do we receive any automatic notification upon request or we have to call any function.
Please help me.I will be highly obliged for your precious answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand few things in **`smack`**. e.g you need to add a `packet listner` so that you have access to all the `packets`. without registering your listner you won't get any packet but smack will still get those and even print those in logcat. So register your listner and set the debugger = true in smack configuration so it prints all the packets in **`logcat`** and you can understand better.

Secondly, Yes, B will get the packet ("notification") that A has added you ,now base on `Roster subscription settings`, decision will be taken.

Thirdly, as per my knowledge, you will receive these subscription/presence packets whenever B gets online. so you have that place to take your action.

I would really recommend you to check the **official docs** here:
[Smack Docs](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/documentation/)

Comment: can you provide me the sample code for incoming subscription request listener as stanza listener is listening incoming messages not subscription requests

Comment: there is another function 'accept' you need to tell here which packets you are accepting and which not. if you had implement this, show me the code for this func

Comment: http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.html#addAsyncStanzaListener-org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaListener-org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.StanzaFilter-

Comment: Farhan, my implementation is on this url,i have posted question for that part too Url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206137/how-can-i-listen-incoming-subscription-request-in-smack-openfire-android